# Sending TCP/IP request from website using local port

Tags: java, php, asp.net, tcp, tcpclient

I want to create a web utility which will use a local port for sending a TCP/IP request.

Does it possible to use a client side port to send a TCP/IP request?

I know it is possible if we send a TCP/IP request from a web server and the specific port is allowed on server. But I want to send the request using the client side port.

What would I need to do? Should I create a Java Applet/Plugin or is it possible using  PHP/.net?

Comment: I think you need to clarify what you're trying to accomplish. It sounds like you're trying to access some sort of TCP/IP service, but is that something running on a server under your control, or someone else's server, or what?

Comment: The service is running on a separate hardware which accepts specific commands over TCP/IP on a certain port.I want to create a web app that sends TCP/IP requests using the local port(client side).

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you want to do, but fundamentally you can't initiate operations on the client using server side code like PHP.

Javascript is capable of some networking operations using XHR (Ajax) and [WebSockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket), and wrapping libraries such as [socket.io](http://socket.io). Perhaps that will suffice for your needs.

A Java Applet will be more capable, but will be [restricted in what it can do](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html) unless you sign the code. And of course will be slower to start up for the client.